# Determine the type of the past tense used in the given sentence

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Which tense is used in the following sentence?

> The repair shop was already closed?

According to me, it is not past simple, as the structure of past simple is subject + second form of main verb + object, and in the given statement there are two verbs, was and closed, both are in their second verb form.

Comment: It's past tense. _Was_ is the singular past tense form of the verb _be_.

Comment: It's past tense even if if it's not an adjective; other constructions, like passive, are not tenses. English, like all Germanic languages, only has two tenses -- present and past. Everything else is constructions, with auxiliary verbs and adverbs and complementizers and idioms and particles and whatnot and so forth; and these are **not** tenses. No matter what your teacher told you. Nobody but your teacher cares about them anyway.

Comment: The repair shop was already open.